# How do I display the sub-items in an array with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, arrays

I have an array where I'm displaying items and their sub-items.

For example, I want to display:

```
1x Margarita Pizza (23)
 - Ham (5)
```

etc.

Right now, it's only displaying the `Margarita Pizza` part, not the `Ham` part. Note that each item may have many sub-items.

Here is the structure:

[image]

I basically only need `sub_item_name` and `price_pretty` displayed. And here's what I got so far:

```
if ( data.raw_data.length>0){
  $.each( data.raw_data, function( key, val ) {               
    htm+='<ons-list-item class="center">'+val.qty+'x '+val.item_name+' ('+val.total_pretty+')</ons-list-item> ';
  });   
}
```

I tried to access it with `data_raw_data.sub_item` but no luck :(

Comment: Try val.sub_item

Comment: `data.raw_data.sub_item`?